# Skip before_validation on: :create in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, before-filter

I am having issues testing a rather simple thing, i.e. duplicity of codes not being allowed in the db.

Let's say I have this model:

```rb
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :series, :sec_code
  validates_uniqueness_of :code, scope:[:series,:sec_code]

  before_validation :generate_codes, on: :create  


  private
  def generate_codes
    self.code=rand.to_s[2..9]  #-> 8 digit code
    self.sec_code=rand.to_s[2..4] #-> 2 digit security code
    self.series=('A'..'Z').to_a.sample #-> one character series
  end

end
```

Then I would like to test that the uniqueness validation does work, in this way:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Ticket do
  before do
    @ticket=Ticket.create
  end
  subject{@ticket}

  it{ should respond_to(:code)}
  ...

  describe ", duplicate codes" do
    before do
      dup_ticket=@ticket.dup
      #Here lays the problem since this calls `generate_codes` 
      #before saving, so it ends up not being a duplicate!
      dup_ticket.save  #<--- 
    end
    it{ should_not be_valid}
  end

end
```

I was considering the use of `after_initialize`, but this is called everytime the object is instantiated, i.e. after being extracted from the DB, which is not desired.
I was wondering, why is `generate_codes` called even when there is an `on: :create` at the filter callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by **jklina**'s answer/comment, I found out that using `update_attribute` helps in this case, and I can update the field without triggering the before validation callbacks.
So the test turns into:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Ticket do
  before do
    @ticket=Ticket.create
  end
  subject{@ticket}

  it{ should respond_to(:code)}
  ...

  describe ", duplicate codes" do
    before do
      dup_ticket=@ticket.dup
      dup_ticket.update_attribute(:code, @ticket.code)
      dup_ticket.update_attribute(:sec_code, @ticket.sec_code)
      dup_ticket.update_attribute(:series, @ticket.series)
    end
    it{ should_not be_valid}
  end

end
```

Hence reflecting the same value for `code`, `sec_code`, and `series` at the ActiveRecord table. And the test does what it's expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

You could try stubbing the generate_codes method to return what you want. So maybe adding:

`allow(dup_ticket).to receive(:generate_codes).and_return(nil)`

I can't test this, but this might prevent the record from generating new values. I'm not completely familiar with `dup` so you'll want to make sure that `dup` carries the code values over as well.

Comment: I will try that, thanks! although I would *really* try to avoid mocking&stubbing tbh, if possible. :/

Comment: Since all the codes appear to be accessible you could use `dup_ticket.update_attributes(code: @ticket.code ...)`. This will save the record and not run the generate_codes command since you seem to only have it on `create`

Comment: I also thought about that, but I assumed `save` would be called, and indeed it does not help. However! If I use `update_attribute` instead, the callback is not "executed", and this does work at the end!